# Python adding players to a game

Tags: python, integer, dice

Okay I'm writing a little game to practice my python since I'm learning, I've learned quite a bit over the past week, but with this certain game I'm puzzled.

its a dice rolling game (boring I know) but, its good hands on practice

What I want the program to do, is ask the user how many people are playing,
then take the integer that the user inputs and roll the dice accordingly to how many people are playing

like if I input 3 it rolls the dice 3 times.

Comment: If we gave you the answer wouldn't that defeat the purpose of you learning python?

Comment: And what's you question? If you are stuck with anything in particular, tell us. An example (input and expected output) helps, too.

Comment: Your code should do the following: 1. Read Input 2. Loop as many times as there are players 3. In each iteration of the loop generate a random number between 1 and 6 and print to screen. All of these are easily done.

Comment: Please post your code so we can comment on it.

Answer (score 0):

This should work for what you are trying to do:

```
import random

try:
    num_players = input("How many people are playing?")
    die_rolls = []

    for i in range(1,num_players + 1):
        die_rolls.append(random.randint(1,6))
    print die_rolls
except:
    print "Error"
```